# ArchLinux multi GPU with different GPU types

Tags: multiple-monitors, xorg, arch-linux

I have a Thinkpad T420 with a Intel HD 3000 and a EXP GDC ExpressCard eGPU adaptor with a ZOTAC Geforce GT 630 attached to it. I have two monitors connected to the GT 630 and want to have an additional monitor driven by the internal GPU.

I found some posts where people were using GPUs of the same manufacturer und thus the same driver, but is it possible to use different GPU types simultaniously with X?

I have a xorg.conf as follows:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    VendorName "NVIDIA"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:05:00:0"
    Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device1"
    VendorName "Intel"
    Driver "intel"
    BusID "PCI:00:02:0"
    Screen 0
EndSection
```

The two monitors attached to the GT 630 work fine and according to the Xorg logfile both drivers are loaded, but the monitor attached to the internal adaptor is not shown by `xrandr -q`.